# Prolog: copy list to already assigned list

Tags: prolog

I am struggling with something that I feel should be very simple, but doesn't seem to be in Prolog! I would like to make List2 equal to List1, where List2 has already been assigned in the past (i.e. it is not a variable).

If `List2` were a variable, I could simply unify `List1` and `List2`:

```
List2=List1.
```

But in my case `List2` already exists (and is not equal to `List1`) and so this predicate fails.

I have also tried the following:

```
copy(List1,List2).
copy(L,R) :- CCp(L,R).
CCp([],[]).
CCp([H|T1],[H|T2]) :- CCp(T1,T2).
```

But this also fails, presumably for the same reason?

Could someone steer me in the right direction? I am teaching myself Prolog so apologies if I am just overlooking something simple. Thanks.

---

Context:

I am trying to add a term `L` to a list `List2` each time a predicate `add_to_list` is run. So far I have the following:

```
add_to_list(List2,List1):-
generateL(L),
( \+ memberchk(L,List2) -> List1=[L|List2]  ; List1 = List2).
```

So I was hoping there was a way to then reassign List2 so as to be equal to List1, but perhaps this is not the Prolog way of thinking.

Instead, I have now attempted to pass through List1 as follows:

```
my_predicate(List1,ListOut):-
    add_to_list(List1,ListOut),
    write(ListOut),nl,nl.

add_to_list(List2,List1):-
   generateL(L),
   ( \+ memberchk(L,List2) -> List1=[L|List2]  ; List1 = List2).
```

This works when I call `my_predicate` as follows: my_predicate([],ListOut), i.e. List1 is empty (as it is to start with). But I would now like to be able to call `my_predicate` subsequent times with `my_predicate(List1,ListOut)` so that a pre-existing `List1` is taken as the input.

Comment: This seems to me as if you try imperative thinking. What is the context of your question? (You try to do something that seems needless to me in Prolog. So, I guess, you have a concept/assumption in mind which differs from Prolog's assumptions. By telling us the context, we can identify that assumption and clarify the differences using our way of thinking.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing variable to reassign (Prolog)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282034/forcing-variable-to-reassign-prolog)

Comment: thanks. I have made edits above to give the context.

Comment: I think this needs an even broader context to determine the right Prolog solution. Are you attempting to call `my_predicate` multiple times on the same list? If you're trying to do this "all at once", then you could just use a recursive predicate, or even, `setof(L, generate(L), ListOut)` which would eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can not "modify" a variable after it is bound. See by example:

[Forcing variable to reassign (Prolog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282034/forcing-variable-to-reassign-prolog)

[Prolog: Changing a variable between two known values consecutivly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369060/prolog-changing-a-variable-between-two-known-values-consecutivly)

when executing your rules "copy" or "ccp" over two already bound variables, prolog will verify if they are equals and fail if not, but not reassign. If some of them is not bound, it will made them equal. If some of them is partially unbound (some list items unbound) it will made equal the unbound items and verify the remainders.

If you present the full context of problem, we could suggest alternatives.

Comment: Small comment: there is one type of variables you can change, the non-backtrackable store.

Comment: Somewhere in your answer the word "unify" should appear. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for steering me in the right direction - I managed to solve it myself in the end, by calling `my_predicate` recursively, as follows:

```
 my_predicate(List2,Num):-
     add_to_list(List2,List1),
     (  Num_new < 99 -> my_predicate(List1,Num_new) ; true  ).

 add_to_list(List2,List1):-
     generateL(L),
     ( \+ memberchk(L,List2) -> List1=[L|List2]  ; List1 = List2).
```

I.e. basically, on each recursion loop, List1 (the new list) is passed through as List2 (the old list).

Comment: yes, this is te way. Probably you will need define "Num_new", as "succ(Num,Num_new)".